Leaflet.PixiOverlay Assets
I'm trying to implement PixiOverlay plugin for my Leaflet Map (Using with react native webview) to improve my map performance (it's lagging when only 20 markers).
            var pixiOverlay = (function() {
                var firstDraw = true;
                var prevZoom;
                var polygonLatLngs = [
                    [51.509, -0.08],
                    [51.503, -0.06],
                    [51.51, -0.047],
                    [51.509, -0.08]
                ];
                var projectedPolygon;

                var circleCenter = [51.508, -0.11];
                var projectedCenter;
                var circleRadius = 85;

                var triangle = new PIXI.Graphics();
                var circle = new PIXI.Graphics();

                var pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
                pixiContainer.addChild(triangle, circle);

                return L.pixiOverlay(function(utils) {
                    var zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom();
                    var container = utils.getContainer();
                    var renderer = utils.getRenderer();
                    var project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
                    var scale = utils.getScale();

                    if (firstDraw) {
                        projectedPolygon = polygonLatLngs.map(function(coords) {return project(coords);});

                        projectedCenter = project(circleCenter);
                        circleRadius = circleRadius / scale;
                    }
                    if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
                        triangle.clear();
                        triangle.lineStyle(3 / scale, 0xFF0000, 1);
                        triangle.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.2);
                        projectedPolygon.forEach(function(coords, index) {
                            if (index == 0) triangle.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
                            else triangle.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
                        });
                        triangle.endFill();

                        circle.clear();
                        circle.lineStyle(3 / scale, 0xFF0000, 1);
                        circle.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
                        circle.drawCircle(projectedCenter.x, projectedCenter.y, circleRadius);
                        circle.endFill();
                    }

                    firstDraw = false;
                    prevZoom = zoom;
                    renderer.render(container);
                }, pixiContainer, {
                    padding: 0.2,
                    forceCanvas: false
                });
            })();
            pixiOverlay.addTo(map);

The code above draw a triangle which is works
          const markerTexture = await PIXI.Assets.load('./img/ic.png');

            const markerLatLng = [51.51, -0.047];   
            // const marker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture);
            const marker = PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture);
            
            marker.anchor.set(27, 75);

            alert('RUN MARKER TEXTURE');

            const pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
            pixiContainer.addChild(marker);

            let firstDraw = true;
            let prevZoom;

            const pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay((utils) => {
                const zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom();
                const container = utils.getContainer();
                const renderer = utils.getRenderer();
                const project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
                const scale = utils.getScale();

                if (firstDraw) {
                    const markerCoords = project(markerLatLng);
                    marker.x = markerCoords.x;
                    marker.y = markerCoords.y;
                    alert(marker.x);
                    alert(marker.y);
                }

                if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
                    marker.scale.set(1 / scale);
                }

                firstDraw = false;
                prevZoom = zoom;
                renderer.render(container);
            }, pixiContainer);

            pixiOverlay.addTo(map);

But when comes to assets like marker from PNG. It seems to stuck at markerTexture await, there won't be any alert after that
"const markerTexture = await PIXI.Assets.load('./img/ic.png');"
Please help me! Tks!
I have looked around PixiOverlay example and it still does not work
